# Does the RabbitMQ Java client have a publishing thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, client, threadpool

I'm making thread dumps from a TCP server application and have noticed some extra threads in the dump. I'm having trouble understanding whether the RabbitMQ Java client has any relationship to them.

I know the client uses a consumer thread pool and I've named its threads `rabbitmq-#` as shown in the partial dump below, however it seems to me that the extra threads (named `pool-1-thread-#`) belong to a publishing thread pool. All my publications wait for confirmations during a few seconds. Looking at the library [source code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_0/src/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ChannelN.java) this suspicion doesn't seem to make much sense, however there is no other suspicious portion I can think of in the application.

Can anyone familiar with the RabbitMQ Java client provide any clue regarding this behavior?

**Bonus question:** since we're at it, can anyone tell how many threads the consumer thread pool usually allocates?

This is my publishing code:

```
public void escrever(JSONObject json) throws DeveDerrubarOProcessoException {
    try {
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(fila, true, false, false, null);
        channel.confirmSelect();
        channel.basicPublish(exchange, routingKey, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10 * 1000);
        channel.close();
        logger.println("Escreveu na fila pacote '" + TipoDePacote.encontrarPeloNumero(json.getInt("tipoPacote")).getDescricao() + "': " + json.toString());
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        if (connection.isOpen()) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch(IOException e2) {
                // Não precisa fazer nada
            }
        }
        throw new DeveDerrubarOProcessoException(e);
    }
}
```

Partial thread dump:

```
"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8279800 nid=0x41a7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f29a5d93000]
"AMQP Connection 172.16.10.23:5672" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b829e800 nid=0x41ae runnable [0x00007f29a526c000]
"AMQP Connection 172.16.10.23:5672" #8 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8247000 nid=0x41a5 runnable [0x00007f29a5f95000]
"Attach Listener" #1410 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f298401a800 nid=0x5059 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"autenticacao-106455" #152589 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296813f800 nid=0x5658 waiting on condition [0x00007f295c98a000]
"autenticacao-106459" #152595 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29680f1000 nid=0x566c waiting on condition [0x00007f294cf91000]
"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8130800 nid=0x41a2 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b812d800 nid=0x41a1 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"DestroyJavaVM" #20 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8008800 nid=0x4187 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8100800 nid=0x4198 in Object.wait() [0x00007f29a6804000]
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b801d800 nid=0x418e runnable
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b801f000 nid=0x418f runnable
"keepalive-102364" #146738 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296402c000 nid=0x7b18 waiting on condition [0x00007f29524e6000]
"keepalive-102467" #146882 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f297802f000 nid=0x7d1d waiting on condition [0x00007f2949f61000]
"keepalive-102849" #147429 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29801f7800 nid=0x72c waiting on condition [0x00007f295e4a5000]
...
"keepalive-106446" #152576 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f297c56b000 nid=0x560f waiting on condition [0x00007f2957c3d000]
"leitura-1003" #1437 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29680f8000 nid=0x50b3 runnable [0x00007f294bc7e000]
"leitura-102508" #146942 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000000a0e800 nid=0x7dca runnable [0x00007f295c485000]
"leitura-103344" #148137 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000008ca000 nid=0x12dc runnable [0x00007f2955718000]
...
"leitura-99604" #142787 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296810e000 nid=0x3e9a runnable [0x00007f2959253000]
"pool-1-thread-2" #9 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b824c000 nid=0x41a6 waiting on condition [0x00007f29a5e94000]
"pool-1-thread-3" #73 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296c01d800 nid=0x420c waiting on condition [0x00007f29a4a64000]
"pool-1-thread-4" #75 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296c01b800 nid=0x420e waiting on condition [0x00007f2989660000]
"pool-1-thread-5" #76 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296c02d800 nid=0x420f waiting on condition [0x00007f2989862000]
"pool-1-thread-6" #77 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f296c02e800 nid=0x4210 waiting on condition [0x00007f29a4b65000]
"rabbitmq-2" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b82a0800 nid=0x41af waiting on condition [0x00007f29a516b000]
"rabbitmq-3" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2978002000 nid=0x41b0 waiting on condition [0x00007f29a506a000]
"rabbitmq-4" #14510 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f297802d800 nid=0x1857 waiting on condition [0x00007f295a96a000]
"rabbitmq-5" #69858 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2978029800 nid=0x5f93 waiting on condition [0x00007f2948e50000]
"rabbitmq-6" #69885 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f297802a000 nid=0x6009 waiting on condition [0x00007f2956122000]
"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b80fe800 nid=0x4197 in Object.wait() [0x00007f29a6905000]
"seqcomando-102" #395 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000000902800 nid=0x43c6 waiting on condition [0x00007f2956829000]
"seqcomando-1024" #3392 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000009d8800 nid=0x706b waiting on condition [0x00007f294d597000]
"seqcomando-103" #398 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000091b800 nid=0x43c9 waiting on condition [0x00007f2956526000]
...
"seqcomando-9740" #32230 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000009fc000 nid=0x26a2 waiting on condition [0x00007f294ba7c000]
"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8150000 nid=0x41a3 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b812b800 nid=0x41a0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b8162800 nid=0x41a4 waiting on condition
"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f29b80f9000 nid=0x4193 runnable
```